# Excel count occurrences of two terms across rows

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, countif

I have a schedule made in an Excel sheet. I'm trying to count the occurrences of two terms across a row. For example, how many times did Person A work an "on call" shift? Example Example sheet [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r0D4jZSM-cq271wliAyM4_SakiJbcFvY/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: What is the second term? `on call` and??

Comment: Sounds like COUNTIFS  for AND or adding 2 COUNTIFS for OR.

Comment: Also, do you want to count the occurrences up for the whole week?

Comment: @Tom-Sharpe Yes, ideally a formula to find out how many "on call" shifts each person (Person A, Person B, Person C, and Person D) worked for the whole week.

Comment: @urdearboy the first term is the person (ex. Person A) and the second term is "on call"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an array-type formula to check each cell to see if it contains "On call" and belongs to a given person. The formula would start in B2 of a new sheet and be pulled down to B3 etc.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Schedule!$A$1:$R$23="On Call")*(Schedule!$A$1:$A$23=A2))
```

assuming your schedule is in a sheet called "Schedule" and the people's names are in A2, A3 etc. of another sheet.

[image]

Or perhaps more usefully if you put the different shift types into the first row of the summary sheet

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Schedule!$A$1:$R$23=B$1)*(Schedule!$A$1:$A$23=$A2))
```

[image]

Comment: this is PERFECT. Thank you!